# Search for keyword appearances and direct output to file

Tags: unix, command-line

I'm looking to find appearances of a keyword across my site. So, for example, I search for "Digital Currency", inside all files apart from .pdf. I would like to output the result (filename where word appears) to a file and add a new line after every entry in that file if possible.

Adding the line number where the result appears would be great too, but one thing at a time.

I have mashed together two commands to try and come close to this, neither of which work as expected.

```
grep -rl "Digital Currency" --exclude "*.pdf" >> wordcount-digital-currency.txt

find /home/ukglobal/public_html/ -exec grep -H -r -n 'Digital Curency' "*.html" --exclude "*.pdf" {} \ >> wordcount-digital-currency.html;
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with these commands/how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is enough:

```
grep -nr "Digital Currency" --exclude "*.pdf" \
     --exclude wordcount-digital-currency.txt > wordcount-digital-currency.txt
```

if you want to exclude the matching line, use `cut`:

```
grep -nr "Digital Currency" --exclude "*.pdf" | \
      cut -d: -f1,2 > wordcount-digital-currency.txt
```

from the [grep man-page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/grep/):

```
-l, --files-with-matches

          Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print the name of each input
          file from which output would normally have  been  printed.   The
          scanning  will  stop  on  the  first match.  (-l is specified by
          POSIX.)
```

Answer (score 0):

To search for the occurence of a string SEARCH_STRING in a file and write the file name to another file NEW_FILE_NAME

```
for i in `ls -1tr`
{
SEARCH_STRING_LINE_NO=`grep -n SEARCH_STRING i | cut -d: -f1`;
if [ SEARCH_STRING_LINE_NO > 0 ] then
FILE_NAME >> NEW_FILE_NAME
fi
}
```

Minor syntax mistakes aside, this should atleast guide u to yr goal